# basic MERGE into same table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

What I am trying to do is insert/update different versions into a product table. This is a PL/SQL chunk and i have a variable that holds the version number. Lets say the version is 10. Now, I wanna use the merge statement to insert or update versions 11 - 15 for the same product. So, I need to check the table for existing product & version(I have product_id). I need to generate numbers 11 through 15 and check it against the table along with product_id. So, my question is in the using clause - i need to generate the version numbers(11-15) using my temp variable that holds 10 and supplement as my second column(version). Please update the base MERGE statement i have below for my requirement. Thanks.

```
MERGE INTO product a
USING (SELECT product_id,
              version_id/variable
         FROM product
        WHERE product_id = 1234
      ) b 
      ON (a.product_id = b.product_id AND a.version_id = b.version_id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
    [UPDATE product]
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    [INSERT INTO product]
```

Comment: What's the logic for determining that it's 11-15? If it's just "values higher than 10" then use a.version_id > b.version_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a row generator, e.g. this will generate version IDs 11 to 15 for your query, so that your merge can insert/update them as required:

```
MERGE INTO product a
USING (SELECT product.product_id,
              q.version_id
         FROM product
             ,(SELECT ROWNUM+10 version_id FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5) q
        WHERE product_id = 1234
      ) b 
ON (a.product_id = b.product_id AND a.version_id = b.version_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  [UPDATE product]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  [INSERT INTO product]
```

Comment: Question: can't the `(SELECT product.product_id,
              q.version_id
         FROM product
             ,(SELECT ROWNUM+10 version_id FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5) q
        WHERE product_id = 1234
      ) b` part be simplified to `(SELECT ROWNUM+10 version_id, '1234' product_id FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5) b` ?

Comment: @bernardpaulus you could, except that you would then be making the assumption that a row with product_id = 1234 exists in the table (which may or may not be true). Also, querying the product table means if we need other columns from the product table they are available to us.

Answer (score 15):

The selected answer is a bit complex, so here is my answer to merge into the same table

```
MERGE INTO YOUR_TABLE
USING DUAL
    ON ( USER_ID = '123' AND USER_NAME= 'itszaif') 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ( USERS_ID, USER_NAME)
        VALUES ('123','itszaif');
```

This command checks if `USER_ID` and `USER_NAME` are matched, if not matched then it will insert.

Comment: This is a good simple example because, if you're only using one table, you have to use the select 1 from dual and in the ON, enter the criteria, based on the primary key for the table.  I updated the example, notice you can't update the primary key fields, I'm changing some fields I made up for the example.